# Terraform "count" create only one resource

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create as many resources as defined in variable as well as create  `GlobalSecondaryIndexName` dimension only if variable is set to `global_secondary_index_name`, however I can't figure out how can I do it with multiple conditions. Following configuration wants to create just one resource. Here is the resource configuration:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dynamodb_units" {
  count                     = length(var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"]) > 0 && var.aws_environment == "environment" ? 1 : 0
  alarm_name                = join("", ["DynamoDB read capacity thoughput on ", var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"][count.index], " table is exceeding threshold"])
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_eval_periods"][count.index]
  metric_name               = "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits"
  namespace                 = "AWS/DynamoDB"
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  threshold                 = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_threshold"][count.index]
  alarm_description         = "The number of read capacity units consumed over the specified time period"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions             = []
  ok_actions                = []

  dimensions = {
    TableName                = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"][count.index]
    GlobalSecondaryIndexName = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"] == "secondary_index_name" ? 1 : 0
  }
}
```

variables:

```
environment_vars = {
  cloudwatch = {
    dynamodb_table_list = [
        "x","y","z"
    ]
    dynamodb_table_eval_periods = [
        "1","2","3"
    ]
    dynamodb_table_threshold = [
        "100","100","200"
    ]
    dynamodb_table_secondary_index = [
        "global_secondary_index_name"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a [ternary condition](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals) for your `count` value. The ternary condition is:

`length(var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"]) > 0 && var.aws_environment == "environment"`

This translates to:

> if `length(var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"])` is greater than `0`, and `var.aws_environment` is equal to `"environment"`

The `true` expression for your ternary operator has a value of `1`, the `false` expression for your ternary operator has a value of `0`.

---

You have hard-coded count values of `1` and `0` depending on the condition. Your question states that the code only wants to create one resource, but you have a hard-coded value of `1` so it is entirely unclear what else you would expect to happen here.

I'm just guessing, from looking at your code, and your variables, but I think you want to create one resource for each entry of `dynamodb_table_list`. If that's the case, then change the hard-coded value of `1` to be the length of the list:

```
count = length(var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"]) > 0 && var.aws_environment == "environment" ? length(var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"]) : 0
```

---

This line is going to be a problem though:

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexName = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"] == "secondary_index_name" ? 1 : 0
```

I can't even venture a guess as to what you are trying to do on that line. This list `var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"]` is obviously never going to equal to the string value of `"secondary_index_name"`, and in either case, you are trying to assign a value of `1` or `0` to the `GlobalSecondaryIndexName` attribute, which is not a valid name for a Global Secondary Index.

---

**EDIT:**

> what I want is to this value be populated only if TableName = secondary_index_name and not be created otherwise.

In that case, the code would probably look like this (fixing the condition to check the actual table name, then setting either a value for the GlobalSecondaryIndex, or `null`), assuming that the value in `dynamodb_table_secondary_index` is the GSI name:

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexName = var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_list"][count.index] == "secondary_index_name" ? var.environment_vars["cloudwatch"]["dynamodb_table_secondary_index"][0] : null
```

Comment: Thanks for count condition that worked. GlobalSecondaryIndexName dimension is my bad, what I want is to this value be populated only if TableName = secondary_index_name and not be created otherwise. Not sure if this is possible at all.

Comment: @DisplayName I updated my answer with the GSI name based on your comment.